# Creating custom JQuery objects and functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have created a simple JQuery extension :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        GMselect: function(options){ 
            var defaults = {
                url: '',
                onSelect: function(){},
                loadData: function(url){
                    $.get(url || this.url).done(function(res){
                       var opts = '';
                       for (i in res){
                           opts += '<option value='+res[i].id+'>'+res[i].name + '</option>';
                       }
                       me.html(opts); 
                    });
                }
            };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            options.loadData();
            $(this).change( options.onSelect );
            var me = $(this);
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

this way I can easly create select elements reading data from remote JSON source like this:

```
$('#mySelect').GMselect({
    url: 'getData'
});
```

This part is clear, however I would like to know  the way to dynamically reload the select, by invoking the method like

```
$('#mySelect').reload(url)
```

Any help and comments will be appreciate

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think this could work  basically making defaults a private object of the plugin to be able to play with it in all the functions (reuse the **loadData** function).

```
(function($) {

            var defaults = {
                url: '',
                onSelect: function(){},
                loadData: function(me,url){
                $.get(url || this.url).done(function(res){
                       var opts = '';
                       for (i in res){
                           opts += '<option value='+res[i].id+'>'+res[i].name + '</option>';
                       }
                       me.html(opts); 
                    });
                }
            };
            $.fn.extend({
                GMselect: function(options){ 
                    var me = $(this);
                    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
                    options.loadData(me);
                    $(this).change( options.onSelect );
                },
                    reload:function(url){
                    var me = $(this);
                    defaults.loadData(me,url)
                }
            });
    }(jQuery));
```

Call with GMSelect:

```
$("#mySelect").GMselect({url:"JSON.json"})
```

`JSON.json` file:

```
[{"id":10,"name":"Apple"},{"id":45,"name":"Melon"},{"id":12,"name":"Kiwi"}]
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Call with reload:

```
$("#mySelect").reload("JSON2.json")
```

`JSON2.json` file:

```
[{"id":10,"name":"RED"},{"id":45,"name":"PURPLE"},{"id":12,"name":"BLACK"}]
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Basically the changes made were to add the function reload and make `defaults` private inside the plugin to use it in all the functions available in this case the `defaults.loadData(me,url)` inside the function reload.

Comment: @user3460254 Feel free to mark the question as accepted if it was the one that helped you. Have a nice day